# Firebase Storage remove custom metadata key

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I couldn't remove a custom metadata key from a file in Firebase storage.

This is what I tried so far:

```
blob = bucket.get_blob("dir/file")
metadata = blob.metadata
metadata.pop('custom_key', None) # or del metadata['custom_key']
blob.metadata = metadata
blob.patch()
```

I also tried to set its value to `None` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are some reasons that could be affecting you to delete the custom metadata. I will address them individually, so it's easier for understanding.

First, it seems that when you read the metadata with `blob.metadata`, it only returns as a read-only - as clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145047/set-metadata-in-google-cloud-storage-using-gcloud-python). So, your updates will not work as you would like, using the way you are trying. The second reason, it seems that saving the metadata again back to `blob`, follows a different order than what you are trying - as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366142/how-to-access-file-metadata-for-files-in-google-cloud-storage-from-a-python-go).

You can give it a try using the below code:

```
blob = bucket.get_blob("dir/file")
metadata = blob.metadata
metadata.pop{'custom_key': None} 
blob.patch()
blob.metadata = metadata
```

**While this code is untested**, I believe it might help you changing the orders and avoid the `blob.metadata` read-only situation.

In case this doesn't help you, I would recommend you to raise an issue for in the official [Github repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python) for the Python library on Cloud Storage, for further clarifications from the developers.