# Missing custom headers in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

1. I've created Standard Storaget Type bucket in my GCS console with public access restriction
2. I've put a little file inside this bucket and add custom metadata ("name":"jack") using GUI
3. I've created simple Python script for downloading this file:

from pathlib import Path
import requests

```
def url_retrieve(url: str, outfile: Path):
    R = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    if R.status_code != 200:
        raise ConnectionError('could not download {}\nerror code: {}'.format(url, R.status_code))

    print(R.history)
    print(R.headers)
    print(R.status_code)
    outfile.write_bytes(R.content)

url_retrieve(url, path)
```

I pass url from "Authenticated URL" field in object inside GCS Console GUI.

Problem: There is no my custom metadata inside headers. What am i doing wrong? :)

Example Response Headers:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: __Host-GAPS=1:YbfLYYNRk-YoqA4WaishOZQsoWZyKg:Mgn4RZDSaVcAMUG4; Expires=Wed, 07-May-2025 08:51:52 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; Priority=HIGH
x-auto-login: realm=com.google&args=service%3Dcds%26continue%3Dhttps://storage.cloud.google.com/kravtsov-test-bucket/tox_01.tox
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 08 May 2023 08:51:52 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy-Report-Only: same-origin; report-to="AccountsSignInUi"
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-4gxVLMlbGh5kkUnB0MDL4g' 'unsafe-inline';object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /v3/signin/*/AccountsSignInUi/cspreport;worker-src 'self'
Content-Security-Policy: require-trusted-types-for 'script';report-uri /v3/signin/*/AccountsSignInUi/cspreport
Accept-CH: Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-WoW64, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site
Report-To: {"group":"AccountsSignInUi","max_age":2592000,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/report-to/AccountsSignInUi"}]}
Permissions-Policy: ch-ua-arch=*, ch-ua-bitness=*, ch-ua-full-version=*, ch-ua-full-version-list=*, ch-ua-model=*, ch-ua-wow64=*, ch-ua-platform=*, ch-ua-platform-version=*
Server: ESF
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site,Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: What is the header and what headers are being returned? Edit your post with those details.

Comment: Please format the update correctly. One big line is hard to read.

Comment: Do you mean that you set custom metadata on the object: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#custom-metadata

Comment: @JohnHanley Yeap, custom metadata

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366142/how-to-access-file-metadata-for-files-in-google-cloud-storage-from-a-python-go) & [blog](https://download.huihoo.com/google/gdgdevkit/DVD1/developers.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've figured it out - thanks to Sathi Aiswarya for pointing me right direction.

So, you won't get any object metadata headers using Authenticated URL from outside of Google Infrastructure. To get those headers you have 2 options:

1. Make your bucket/object public and use Public URL.
2. Generate signed URL for your object.

Script for generating such URL described here - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually. I've used it AS IS and it worked.

For this script you also have to generate private key for your service account. This key is passed as service_account_file parameter in script.

Process of private key creation is described here -
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete